# When do physical partitions get created?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a partitioned collection that uses a 5-digit membership code as its partition key. There could be thousands of partition keys in the collection.

I upserted about 32K documents in it. Using the `Partition Stats` sample:

```
Summary:
        partitions: 1
        documentsCount: 32,190
        documentsSize: 0.045 GB
```

But there is only a single physical partition! If I use the portal metrics, i see a similar thing:

[image]

Doesn't this mean that all my queries are going against a single physical partition? When does Cosmos add more physical partitions?

The reason I ask is because I am seeing really poor performance that seriously deteriorates when I load test. For example this simple count method starts off fast in a light test and then takes seconds when the system is under pressure (ignore the `handler` stuff):

```
    private async Task<int> RetrieveDigitalMembershipRefreshItemsCount(string code, string correlationId)
    {
        var error = "";
        double cost = 0;
        var handler = HandlersFactory.GetProfilerHandler(_loggerService, _settingService);
        handler.Start(LOG_TAG, "RetrieveDigitalMembershipRefreshItemsCount", correlationId);

        try
        {
            if (this._docDbClient == null)
                throw new Exception("No singleton DocDb client!");

            // Check to see if there is a URL
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_docDbDigitalMembershipsCollectionName))
                throw new Exception("No Digital Memberships collection defined!");

            FeedOptions queryOptions = new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = 1, PartitionKey = new Microsoft.Azure.Documents.PartitionKey(code.ToUpper()) };

            return await _docDbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<DigitalMembershipDeviceRegistrationItem>(
                        UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(_docDbDatabaseName, _docDbDigitalMembershipsCollectionName), queryOptions)
                        .Where(e => e.CollectionType == DigitalMembershipCollectionTypes.RefreshItem && e.Code.ToUpper() == code.ToUpper())
                        .CountAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error = ex.Message;
            throw new Exception(error);
        }
        finally
        {
            handler.Stop(error, cost, new
            {
                Code = code
            });
        }
    }
```

Here is the log for this method as the test progresses ordered by the highest duration. Initially it takes only a few milliseconds:

[image]

I tried most of the performance tips i.e. direct mode, same region, singleton. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Partition Key is used for logical partition, distributing data across physical partitions. Physical partition management is managed by Azure Cosmos DB.

Auto-split of physical partition can be achieved, as long as the initial container was created with at least 1000 RU/s of throughput and a partition key is specified. The split mainly distributes logical partitions in one physical partition to different physical partitions. And the process is transparent to us.

Two scenarios for physical parition:

- Provision throughput higher than settings value, Azure Cosmos DB splits one or more of your physical partitions to support the higher throughput.
- Physical partition `p` reaches its storage limit, Azure Cosmos DB seamlessly splits `p` into two new physical partitions. If `p` only has one logical partition inside, split won't occur.

So if those conditions are not met, you only have one single physical partition. But the queries are going against specified logical partition using partition key.

For more details, please refer to [Azure Cosmos DB partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data#how-does-partitioning-work).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I am getting really poor performance from Cosmos....some queries are taking seconds when I run a load test with multiple threads accessing the API (running in App Service which in turn accesses Cosmos) and I see high CPU usage on the API server. When it runs light, things seem to be ok. But it seriously buckles under pressure. So I thought it has to do with the physical partition. I tried most of the performance tips I found. No 429 in the portal metrics...I use 1000 throughput on partitioned collections. Do you have any pointers I can try? Thanks.

Comment: I added code sample and log to the original post so you can see what I am doing. Thanks.